# Unable to set context in Drone plugin drone-gcr (and drone-docker)

Tags: google-container-registry, drone.io

Per this bug [drone docker plugin question](https://discourse.drone.io/t/drone-docker-plugin-plugins-docker-plugins-ecr-to-set-context/6177)...

And per the [documentation](http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-docker/)...

The `context` parameter just doesn't work. I keep getting `file not found` errors in the logs.

How do I set the context in drone-docker and drone-gcr plugins?

```
name: publish
image: plugins/gcr
settings:
  context: subdirectory
  registry: registry.dev
  repo: repoName
  tag: latest
```

I've also tried

```
name: publish
image: plugins/gcr
settings:
  file: Dockerfile
  context: subdirectory
  registry: registry.dev
  repo: repoName
  tag: latest
```

Comment: This question is mostly for myself in the future. This is the second time I spent 30 minutes trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

You must set the `dockerfile` flag as well:

```
name: publish
image: plugins/gcr
settings:
  dockerfile: subdirectory/Dockerfile
  context: subdirectory
  registry: registry.dev
  repo: repoName
  tag: latest
```